# Почему не сохраняются данные в базу данных

Tags: yii2

Столкнулся вот с такой проблемой. Вот код:

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\admin\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\MediaForm;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;


/**
 * Default controller for the `admin` module
 */
class MediaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Renders the index view for the module
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionUpload()
    {
        $model = new MediaForm();

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFile');

            if ($model->upload()) {
                // file is uploaded successfully
                $imageNamesStr = implode(',', $model->imageNames);

                return $this->render('index', [
                    'model' => $model, 

                    ]);
            }
            $model->img_src = $imageNamesStr;
            $model->save();
        }

        return $this->render('upload', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
    }
}
```

Но в базе не появляется новой записи( Подскажите в чем проблема? Вроде все правильно. У меня взята модель, я закидываю в поле img_src строку, и пытаюсь ее сохранить. В результате должна появиться новая запись в БД, где в поле img_src будет закинутая строка, а остальные поля, если не имеют по умолчанию ни чего, то должны ровняться Null. Но ни чего не происходит(

Comment: У MediaForm, как у модели ActiveRecord, есть метод getErrors(), который подскажет вам в чём дело.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но мне это не помогло. Я не смог понять, когда использовать этот метод.